# Envio de cabeceras - CURL PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

Estoy intentando descargar imágenes mediante una API y ubicarlas en un directorio, para poder realizar esto tengo que enviar la autorización de la api a través de un token generado.

Esta es mi función:

```
function urlToFile($url){


 $options = array(
  CURLOPT_FILE    => fopen('/var/www/html/carpeta/custom/modules/carpetas/' . 'imagen.jpg', 'w'),
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT =>  28800, // set this to 8 hours so we dont timeout on big files
  CURLOPT_URL     => $url,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
  'Authorization: Token XXXXX',

));


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

La función descarga un archivo y lo guarda, pero no me lo deja abrir ya que aparece dañado, lo que me hace pensar que quizás no esta llegando la solicitud a la ruta correcta y quizás es por la autorización. Hay algo mal en eso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la logica que compartes parece correcta, el detalle estara en como guardas lo que recibes, si el archivo esta siendo guardado con la extension correcta o el contenido es correcto, puedes intentar mostrando en consola el estado http que recibes al hacer la peticion e imprimir lo que recibes en el response. serviria ademas que pusieras ese codigo que estas usando.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Hola! Si, sin dudas la lógica estaba ok y era de esa forma, estaba errandole a un caracter del token y lo volví a ver luego de confirmar con tu comentario que el método estaba ok.
Gracias. Saludos